# Plotting in R using stat_function on a logarithmic scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having serious problems trying to get my head around `stat_function` in R's `ggplot2`. I started off with this trivial example:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1, 1e4)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = function(x) x)
```

which works as expected. Unfortunately, when I add log scales for both x and y axes so:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1e4), aes(x)) +
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) x)
```

I get the following result, which is a pretty nasty violation of the identity function. 
[image]

Is there something very basic that I'm missing? What is then the correct and least hacky way to plot a function on log scale?

**EDIT:**
Inspired by the answers I went on and experimented with scales and the `aesthetics` parameter. I was even more puzzled to find out that I got what I expected using the code below:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1e4, y = 1:1e4), aes(x, y)) +
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) x)
```

with an apparently unused vector of y values (unused by `stat_function` that is). Do the axis transformations depend on the availability of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `scale_x_log10()` then `x` values are log transformed, and only then used for calculation of `y` values with `stat_function()`. Then `x` values are backtransformed to original values to make scale. `y` values remain as calculated from log transformed `x`. You can check this by plotting values without `scale_y_log10()`. In plot there is straight line.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:1e4), aes(x)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) x) +
    scale_x_log10()
```

If you apply `scale_y_log10()` you log transform already calculated `y` values, so curve is plotted.

Comment: Yes, very good, I was zeroing in on the order in which ggplot did things.

Answer (score 5):

In ggplot2, the rule is that scale transformation precedes statistical transformation which in turn precedes coordinate transformation. In this context, the function (via stat_function()) is the statistical transformation.

If you use a scale_x/y_*() function in a ggplot2 call, it will apply the scale transformation(s) first before computing the function.

Case 0: Plot in the original scales of x and y.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1e4, y = 1:1e4), aes(x, y)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) x)
```

Case 1a: Both x and y are log transformed before the function is computed because of the presence of scale_x/y_log10(). You can see this from the values on their respective scales (compare to Case 0).

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:1e4, y = 1:1e4), aes(x, y)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) x) +
    scale_x_log10() +
    scale_y_log10()
```

Case 1b: x is log transformed in the original data frame. Consequently, the function actually operates on the log10(x) values, so will still be a straight line, but on the log10 scale in both x and y.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = log10(seq(1e4)), y = seq(1e4)), aes(x, y)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) x)
```

Case 1c: The same as 1b, with one exception: the x-scale is in the original units but the y-scale is in log10(x) units, because the scale transformation on x occurs before the statistical transformation f(y) = y is computed, where y = log10(x).

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(1e4), y = seq(1e4)), aes(x, y)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) x) +
    scale_x_log10()
```

Case 2: By contrast, coordinate transformations take place *after* statistical transformation; i.e., the function is computed in the original units first and then the coordinate transformation on x takes place, which warps the function:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(1e4), y = seq(1e4)), aes(x, y)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) x) +
    coord_trans(xtrans = "log10")
```

...unless, of course, you apply the same transformation to both x and y:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(1e4), y = seq(1e4)), aes(x, y)) +
    stat_function(fun = function(x) x) +
    coord_trans(xtrans = "log10", ytrans = "log10")
```