# Add a curve to a log/log scatterplot

Tags: r, plot

I have a scatterplot in a log/log space

```
plot(a,b,log="xy")
```

or in ggplot2

```
qplot(a,b,data="time",log="xy")
```

Now I would like to impose upon this scatter plot the curve f(x)=x*x+2. Butthe function woudl need to be plotted in the logarithmic space as well. How would I do this? Is there an way to do this in ggplot2?

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, `curve` is the command that you're looking for in base graphics.

```
#Make up some data
set.seed(0)
a <- 1:10
b <-(a^2+2)*exp(0.1*rnorm(10))

plot(a,b,log='xy')
curve(x^2+2,add=TRUE)
```

in ggplot2 world:

```
qplot(a,b,data=time)+stat_function(fun=function(x){x^2+2}) + coord_trans(xtrans = "log10",ytrans="log10")
```

from [Plotting in R using stat_function on a logarithmic scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144998/plotting-in-r-using-stat-function-on-a-logarithmic-scale) seems to do what you're after.

Comment: but will curve plot the function (x*x+2) as log/log? otherwise, it would not make sense to superimpose it...?

Comment: is there any elegant way to do this in ggplot2 maybe/

Comment: It's definitely on the log-log scale - e.g. `curve(x^2)` is straight as you'd expect in log-space. Im not sure about the ggplot2 world, although I'd be very surprised if there weren't a similar way to do this.

Comment: Edited answer now to include possibility for ggplot2 solution