# In ggplot2, how do I make stat_function subject to scale_x_log10?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `ggplot2`, how do I make a `stat_function` use the same x scale as the geom layer, for instance `scale_x_log10`?

To illustrate the problem, consider this example:

```
x <- rexp(100)
base <- qplot(x, geom = "density")
base + stat_function(fun = dexp, colour = "red")
```

[image: without scale]

So far so good. But now, I add a scale:

```
base + stat_function(fun = dexp, colour = "red") + scale_x_log10()
```

[image: with scale]

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144998/plotting-in-r-using-stat-function-on-a-logarithmic-scale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be, you can't. There is a predefined order in which ggplot2 does transformations;

1. Scales
2. Statistics
3. Coordinates

Hence, instead of scale transformation, use a *coordinate* transformation.

```
base + stat_function(fun = dexp, colour = "red") + coord_trans(x = "log10")
```

[image]